# Best way to call controller method from template html

Tags: angularjs, typescript, controller

We're using Typescript, but I believe the answer would be the same if it were straight angular...

In my controller, we have various methods:

```
public editMe(editing: boolean): void {
  //do something
}
```

Which are to be called by the html template that the controller uses:

```
<a ng-click="editMe(true)">Edit</a>
```

But I've noticed the method doesn't execute if I don't either use the controllers name in the html, or bind it in the controller such as:

```
$scope.editMe = this.editMe.bind(this);
```

Is this right? It seems to me like a public controller function should automatically get put on the scope for the template to use...? Just want to make sure I'm doing things the right way before I get too far down the rabbit hole. :)

Comment: A public controller method is a member of the controller, not a member of the scope. So you need the controller to call it. Either use controllerAs and use controller methods, or don't use controllerAs, and add functions to the scope, and not to the controller. `$scope.editMe = function() { ... }`

Comment: Ok, thats what I assumed. But whats the preferred way to get the template to call the controller methods? Is the bind preferred? Or is there a different way thats more standard?

Comment: controllerAs is the recommended way.

Comment: Thanks JB. If you post it as a solution, I can give you the pts for it. :)